# Initializing a multidimensional array of GLfloats in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currenty having a knot in my brain as to how to properly initialize an array of GLFloats *line by line*.
As far as I know, an array could be written like this:

```
int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}}
```

In my case, I have the array

```
GLfloat targetVertices[10][72];
```

for the vertices of the six sides of cubes (ten cubes, to be exact). The cube coordinates are stored in the

```
float targetX[10], targetY[10], targetZ[10];
```

arrays. I would like to initialize it like this:

```
for(iii = 0; iii <= 9; iii++) {
    targetVertices[iii] = {                  /*Side 1*/
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                                             /*Side 2*/
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                                             /*Side 3*/
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                                             /*Side 4*/
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                                             /*Side 5*/
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]-1,
                                             /*Side 6*/
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]-1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]+1, targetZ[iii]+1,
                           targetX[iii]+1, targetY[iii]-1, targetZ[iii]+1
                          };
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm always told about a syntax error regarding the very first squiggly bracket (C2059 and C2143, but those don't make any sense to me there).
I hope my question is clear and someone can help me. I have not found anything similar to my problem on this or any other site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your syntax is by saying targetVertices[iii] you re referring to the iiith index of the array, not the entire column. 2D arrays are stored as 1D arrays, but provide [][] for simple access. You can refer to them as single or dual dimensional.

Here is a more reusable way to approach this.

```
void addVertex(std::vector<GLfloat> &data, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    data.push_back(x);
    data.push_back(y);
    data.push_back(z);
}
```

---

```
void addCube(std::vector<GLfloat> &data, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z)
{
    addVertex(data, x-1, y-1, z-1);
    addVertex(data, x-1, y-1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x-1, y+1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x-1, y+1, z-1);

    addVertex(data, x+1, y-1, z-1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y-1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y+1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y+1, z-1);

    addVertex(data, x-1, y-1, z-1);
    addVertex(data, x-1, y-1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y-1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y-1, z-1);

    addVertex(data, x-1, y+1, z-1);
    addVertex(data, x-1, y+1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y+1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y+1, z-1);

    addVertex(data, x-1, y-1, z-1);
    addVertex(data, x-1, y+1, z-1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y+1, z-1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y-1, z-1);

    addVertex(data, x-1, y-1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x-1, y+1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y+1, z+1);
    addVertex(data, x+1, y-1, z+1);
}
```

---

```
void makeCubes(std::vector<GLfloat> &data)
{
    float targetX[10], targetY[10], targetZ[10];
            data.clear();
            data.reserve(720);

    //...initialize the above arrays...

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::vector<GLfloat> newData;
        addCube(newData, targetX[i], targetY[i], targetZ[i]);
        data.insert(data.begin(), newData.begin(), newData.end());
    }
}
```

---

You can easily convert this to a C-array by taking a reference to the first element:

```
std::vector<GLfloat> data;
makeCubes(data);
GLfloat *cArray = &data[0];
```

A call to glBufferData could be made like this:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             data.size()*sizeof(GLfloat),
             &data[0],
             GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try and implement your solution. However, for understanding purposes, why can't I simply assign data line by line to my array? It works for char arrays (at least in ANSI-C). Also, I may have misphrased, since it isn't an initialization per se, but rather an assignment (I do the initialization in two nested for loops beforehand, to all zeroes). Could it maybe work by using the "new" keyword? As in, writing GLfloat *targetVertices; in my header file and in the constructor targetVertices = new GLfloat[][]; or something?

Comment: The problem with your syntax is by saying targetVertices[iii] you re referring to the iiith index of the array, not the entire column. See, 2D arrays are stored as 1D arrays, but provide [][] for simple access. You can refer to them as single or dual dimensional. There would be no need for "new" if you already allocated the 10x72 array.